# Google Analytics for Android not showing anything

Tags: android, google-analytics

I was sure that I followed the documentation for the v4 API correctly, but maybe someone can spot what I've forgotten. I've been working on this for several days now, so I know it's not just Google Analytics taking its sweet time updating.

In my `extends Application` Java file I have

```
public class ASIUSU extends Application {

final private String PROPERTY_ID = "TRACKERIDHERE";
Tracker t;

public void onCreate() {
    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
    }

public Tracker getTracker() {
    return t;
     }
}
```

And in my `MainActivity.java` file's onCreate() I have

```
Tracker t = ((ASIUSU) this.getApplication()).getTracker();
t.setScreenName("MainActivity");
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

For good measure, here's the log data that shows when I launch the app

> 09-08 12:20:48.882 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.892 23604-23604/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@429d6040
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.892 23604-23604/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.892 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.892 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu I/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.892 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.892 23604-23604/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.922 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.922 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.922 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
>
> 09-08 12:20:48.932 23604-23622/com.csu.stan.asiusu V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service PATH: https: PARAMS: v=1, ul=en-us, t=screenview, ht=1410204044192, sr=1080x1776, a=1493402686, an=ASI/USU, tid=TIDHERE, aid=com.csu.stan.asiusu, cid=0de78828-82e6-4de7-9781-8642865f3c6b, av=2.0.0, _u=.nK-AL, cd=MainActivity,

Both realtime and the testing I did last Friday aren't showing up-- everything shows 0 users. Can anyone offer some assistance?

Comment: To answer Alessandro's question, yes I am using the correct Property ID. The UA-XXXXXX-Y number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles onto this, I successfully solved my problem. There is absolutely nothing wrong with my code, and it was trying to send to Google Analytics.

That said, I had an adblocker on my phone, which halts dispatches to Google Analytics. Just disable your adblock and try again, it should work.